# OpenJDK 11 error when running apt update

Tags: apt, dependencies

Recently I have been getting this warning icon on my top bar. Clicking on it tells me:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Error: BrokenCount > 0.' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

When I run `apt update` in a terminal, everything is fine and I get no errors. But when I run `apt upgrade` or `apt --fix-broken install` I get the following error message:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-11-jdk-headless : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11~19-1~18.04) but 11~7-1ubuntu1 is installed
 openjdk-11-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11~19-1~18.04) but 11~7-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't know how to fix the problem. I can not run updates and upgrades on the machine.

Comment: Try to update `openjdk-11-jre-headless`. If that doesn't work: remove `openjdk-11-jre-headless` and do `apt --fix-broken install` again.

Comment: Running `sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jre-headless` also brings up an error.`
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-11-jdk-headless : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11~19-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-11-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11~19-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. Fixed the issue by following steps;

1. Went to Software & Updates.
2. Navigate to "Other Software" Tab.
3. Unchecked the entry "http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu bionic main"

Pressed the Close button.

After that, I ran following commands.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed fix the problem. But does this mean I will no longer get updates to Java using `apt`?

Comment: @tamrat: check again the same entry to install Java.

Answer (score 1):

**this resolved for me.**

1. Went to Software & Updates.
2. Navigate to "Other Software" Tab.
3. remove http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu
4. sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-1*
5. sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update